# Is storing any kind of type (integer, text, date) in a longtext type field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value, database-optimization

I'm developing a CMS that has pages/posts, custom pages/posts and custom fields. Those custom fields will be selected through the UI and attached to a custom page.

For example, we create a custom page/post 'project' that will have a these fields: description, order, price and date.

I don't want to use a table for every page type I have, I just want to use one single table to store every field of every given custom field, the problem is they could have different data types. 
My question is, is it a bad idea (thinking of performance) to store e.g. the order value in a generic longtext type field? Is it better to create a "customvaluestable" with 3 fields (date, integer, text) that stores the value of the customfield depending of its data type and leaving the rest null?

Thanks

Comment: Condolences.  You will end up re-discovering the pains of both designs.  [_Another (partial) solution_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/entity-attribute-value-implementation/)

Answer (score 0):

technically speaking, it's a bad idea ... both ideas, actually. You probably think "I don't want to modify tables all the times", but there are some implications: searching strings is less efficient than searching numbers, dates, ... If you want to put everything into a text field, not only will it take up more space, the searches will all be string searches.

What you should ask yourself is this: What is it, you actually want to achieve? If you want some additional *arbitrary* data to be stored alongside static data, that you won't search in like ever ... json-encode that data and just put it into one field you call "customdata" or whatever. Or use a nosql / keyvalue-store to begin with!

When you want to search for it, go the extra mile, look at how drupal handles custom fields. It's ugly, but at least they are consistent. A number should be stored in a numeric field. (Because lexicographic ordering of numbers is really really weird in string fields...).

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi. So do you think having 4 fields (data, text, float, int, e.g) is a better idea?

Comment: no, i think it bloats your table but will not relieve any of the horror. I would really suggest using a table for each page type.

Comment: Thank you @Jakumi!

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use MySQL 5.7 with its new support for a [native JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) instead. Then you can have your custom fields.

The design you're talking about is called the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Although I dispute that it actually qualifies as a data model.

There are many problems with EAV, since it's fundamentally a non-relational solution implemented in a relational database.

Useful reading:

- [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/)
- [EAV FAIL](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html)
- [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling)

But the bottom line is that you will basically end up creating your own system of metadata about your columns and types -- basically, implementing your own database management system within an RDBMS, which takes a lot of work and introduces a lot of bugs along the way. This is called the [Inner-platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect):

> ... the tendency of software architects to create a system so customizable as to become a replica, and often a poor replica, of the software development platform they are using.